# Azure Toolkit doesn't show up after installation

Tags: eclipse, azure

Azure Toolkit for Eclipse: v.3.25.0
Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers
JDK: 16

From "Eclipse Marketplace" I installed successfully "Azure Toolkit for Eclipse 3.25.0" package, I restarted Eclipse but in toolbar doesn't show the "Tools" button:

[image: in toolbar doesn't show the "Tools" button].

But in "Eclipse Marketplace" it shows up as installed.

[image: But in "Eclipse Marketplace" it shows up as installed.]

I try also to research it.

[image: I try also to research it.]

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation.md),
the Azure Toolkit for Eclipse requires the following software components:

- A Java Developer Kit (JDK), v1.7 or later.

So the reason for this problem is that your jdk version is too low.